# Powershell Comparing two object properties

Tags: powershell

Loaded two JSON files with  `Get-Content filename.JSON | ConvertFrom-Json`

One object name `$SubscriberEmail` has the property name `email`

The second object name `$ADEnabledUsersEmail`  has a property named `Work Email`

Trying to compare both objects and find the ones, not in the `$ADEnabledUsersEmail` object and Write-Out the name.

Here is the current foreach method but seems to output all the emails multiple times.

```
foreach($S in $SubscriberEmail ){
    foreach($A in $ADEnabledUsersEmail){
        if($A.'Work Email' -eq $S.email ){
            Write-Host "User is active"
        }else{
            Write-Host $s.email
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter an `array` you can use `Where-Object` or `.Where()` method or a loop with the right [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#containment-operators). i.e.: `-notin`, `-notcontains`:

```
$SubscriberEmail.email.where({ $_ -notin $ADEnabledUsersEmail.'Work Email' })
```

```
$SubscriberEmail | Where-Object {
    $ADEnabledUsersEmail.'Work Email' -notcontains $_.email
}
```

```
foreach($email in $SubscriberEmail.email)
{
    if($email -notin $ADEnabledUsersEmail.'Work Email')
    {
        $email
    }
}
```

There are many more options to filter `arrays`, just search *filtering arrays powershell* on Google.